# Hi I'm stuck with Lahiri method of drawing sample

Tags: r, statistics

This is the way i'm trying to solve Lahiri method.Dataset given below:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sPklVhO-T9Zj3G_k9ME3qS5ObtChAms2/view?usp=sharing.
About Lahiri Method of drawing sample is given below:
[http://home.iitk.ac.in/~shalab/sampling/chapter7-sampling-varying-probability-sampling.pdf](http://home.iitk.ac.in/%7Eshalab/sampling/chapter7-sampling-varying-probability-sampling.pdf)

on page 6.

I have to implement this concept in R without using packages. Here is some effort i did to solve this question.
Is it possible solve using for loop or i'm totally on wrong path?

```
#Importing Required Library
 library(readr)

#Importing Dataset
 data<- read_csv("P01-03 (1).csv")

#Generating Random Variable 
house_size=data[,2]

#Maximum value of house_size or j
a <- max(house_size);a

 R= runif (35,min=0,max=a);R

for(i in 1:6){
N[i]=sample(N,1,replace=FALSE)
for(j in 1:6){


rn[j]=sample(rn,1,replace=FALSE)
for(k in 1:36){
  

  if (rn[j] < t(house_size)[k]){
    print(rn[k])
  
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: you have to explain to use what Lahiri's sampling scheme is all about, the steps to be taken literarily to achieve that.

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: @DanielJames  About Lahiri Method of drawing sample is given below: http://home.iitk.ac.in/~shalab/sampling/chapter7-sampling-varying-probability-sampling.pdf on page 6.

I have to implement this concept in R without using packages. Here is some effort i did to solve this question. Is it possible solve using for loop or i'm totally on wrong path?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that implements the Lahiri sampling method.

```
lahiri <- function(x, n){
  counts <- table(x)
  #print(counts)
  y <- as.numeric(names(counts))
  N <- length(counts)
  M <- max(counts)
  out <- numeric(n)
  current <- 0L
  while(current < n){
    i <- sample(N, 1)
    j <- sample(M, 1)
    if(j <= counts[i]){
      current <- current + 1L
      out[current] <- y[i]
    }
  }
  out
}

house_size <- data[[2]]

set.seed(2021)
l <- lahiri(house_size, 1000)
bp <- barplot(table(house_size)/sum(house_size), ylim = c(0, 0.04))
points(bp, table(l)/sum(l), col = "blue", pch = 16)
```

[image]

---

### Data

```
library(readr)

google_id <- "1sPklVhO-T9Zj3G_k9ME3qS5ObtChAms2"
google_file <- sprintf("https://docs.google.com/uc?id=%s&export=download", google_id)

#Importing Dataset
data <- read_csv(
  file = google_file,
  col_types = cols(
    `Household No.` = col_double(),
    `Household Size` = col_double(),
    `Cultivated area (acres)` = col_double()
  )
)
```